# How to reuse (rewind) a redirected file in C

Tags: c, input, flush, io-redirection, rewind

I input a text file into my C program by using the `<` I/O redirection in the terminal:

```
MyProgram.exe < "data.txt"
```

And then use `getchar()` and `scanf()` in my code to read from the redirected input. However, as this is a redirected file, I can't use a C file pointer to rewind the buffer.

(I want to count the number of lines in a file of an arbitrary size so I can initialize an array, then I want to re-read the file using `getchar()` and/or `scanf()`).

How do I achieve a rewind or flush when using redirected input?

Comment: you cannot rewind it

Comment: Have you actually tried rewinding it?  fseek works just on on stdin when stdin is a regular file, and when you redirect like this, stdin is a regular file.

Comment: @Lashane: Given that standard input is coming from a disk file, it can be rewound just like any other file stream connected to a disk file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, as this is a redirected file, I cant use a c file pointer to rewind the buffer.

Sure you can! And it's really easy. When a file is being redirected to standard input, `stdin` is a file, so you can treat it just like any other file:

```
rewind(stdin);
```

But keep in mind that this will only work if standard input is being redirected **from a file**. It won't work if standard input is from the terminal or a pipe (e.g, `cat file.txt | myapp`).

Comment: It is just a bad idea to assume `stdin` is a file. The correct way is not to and store the required history instead.